# Scale font size automatically to fit container

Tags: css, font-size

I just remember that there was this very neat (new?) CSS expression to say "hey font, I want you to be exactly this size that you fit into this div container perfectly".

But I'm afraid, I don't remember this cool CSS expression. I'm pretty sure (and hope) that there is one. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure of that specific expression, but using em's is normally the best way to go from a Viewport perspective to ensure your font always sizes correctly/responsively.

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: @Paulie_D No, it is not a duplicate. I don't want to scale the font size with the container just in general, I want it to *fit perfectly* from starting point to end point of the container. Always. An auto detection of font-size if you will, not a responsive readjustment of an existing font size.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CSS container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) to achieve it by using CSS, but it's possible in modern browsers. So I achieved it by using JS(Vue) in this case.

This is an algorithm for finding the appropriate font size to fits its container.

```
<template>
  <component :is="props.element" class="fit-text" :style="{ fontSize: `${props.maxFont}rem` }" ref="componentRef">
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const componentRef = refsE<HTMLElement>();

function changeFontSize() {
  if (!componentRef.value) return;
  const isOverflow = componentRef.value.offsetWidth < componentRef.value.scrollWidth;
  if (!isOverflow) return;
  let fontSize = Number(componentRef.value.style.fontSize.replace(/rem/g, ''));
  const nextFontSize = fontSize - props.step;
  if (nextFontSize < props.minFont) {
    componentRef.value.style.fontSize = `${props.minFont}rem`;
    return;
  }
  componentRef.value.style.fontSize = `${nextFontSize}rem`;
  changeFontSize();
}

onMounted(async () => {
  await nextTick();
  changeFontSize();
});

const props = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{
    element?: string;
    maxFont?: number;
    minFont?: number;
    step?: number;
    maxWidth?: string;
  }>(),
  {
    element: 'p',
    maxFont: 3.25,
    minFont: 1,
    step: 0.5,
    maxWidth: '400px',
  },
);
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.fit-text {
  max-width: v-bind(maxWidth);
  line-height: normal;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of such an expression.
But I can make some advertisement to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/QpXyxv) ;) There you got the container, which is like 420px wide and jQuery calculates the font-size, to fit the container.

I'm on train right now on my mobile and can't write any detailed answer. Sorry for that

```
// some code, bc links to codepen have to be accompanied by code
```

Comment: may i ask what the reason was to downvote this? it's a solution to his question. isn't that, what stackoverflow is about?

Comment: I couldn't say other than answers should have the actual code in them **not links to external sites**. You **actively** circumvented the requirement by adding *non-code* in a **delberate** manner.